# Number handling question in Google spread sheet

Tags: spreadsheet

```
=IF(IsNumber(VALUE(LEFTB(Spending!B4,FIND(",",Spending!B4)-1))),VALUE(LEFTB(Spending!B4,FIND(",",Spending!B4)-1)),0)
```

I have this function in my google sheet, and this is to keep the cell value only if it is numeric value, and replace non-numeric value with 0. But I don't want to use the same function expression,"VALUE(LEFTB(Spending!B4,FIND(",",Spending!B4)-1))",twice. Is there any simple way?

Couldn't find a simple way.